I'm Trying to test my Scheduled Apex Class but Im getting : System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached
I'm trying to create a Test class for a Scheduled Class that calls a Queueable Class
But, it gives me a System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached. error in the test class.
Queueable Class  :
public with sharing class WarehouseCalloutService implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private static final String WAREHOUSE_URL = 'https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment';
    private List<Object> equipments;

    public WarehouseCalloutService() {
        
    }

    private WarehouseCalloutService(List<Object> equipments) {
        // Private constructor for processing data
        this.equipments = equipments;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        if (equipments == null) {
            
            performCallout();
        } else {
            
            processData();
        }
    }

    private void performCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint(WAREHOUSE_URL);

        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            List<Object> deserializedResponse = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            
            
            System.enqueueJob(new WarehouseCalloutService(deserializedResponse));
        }
    }

    private void processData() {
        List<Product2> updatedWarehouseEquipments = new List<Product2>();
        
        for (Object warehouseEquipment : equipments) {
            Map<String,Object> equipment = (Map<String,Object>) warehouseEquipment;        
            Product2 updatedEquipment = new Product2(
                Name = (String) equipment.get('name'),
                Replacement_Part__c = (Boolean) equipment.get('replacement'),
                Cost__c = (Decimal) equipment.get('cost'),
                Current_Inventory__c = (Decimal) equipment.get('quantity'),
                Lifespan_Months__c = (Integer) equipment.get('lifespan'),
                Maintenance_Cycle__c = (Integer) equipment.get('maintenanceperiod'),
                Warehouse_SKU__c = (String) equipment.get('_id')
            );
            updatedWarehouseEquipments.add(updatedEquipment);
        }

        if (!updatedWarehouseEquipments.isEmpty()) {
            upsert updatedWarehouseEquipments Warehouse_SKU__c;
        }
    }
}

Scheduled Class :
    public with sharing class WarehouseSyncSchedule implements Schedulable {
        public static final String cronExp = '0 0 1 * * ?';
        public static final String jobName = 'WarehouseSyncScheduleJob';
    
        public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
            System.enqueueJob(new WarehouseCalloutService());
        }
    
        public static void scheduleJob() {
            try {
                
                abortExistingJob();
                
                
                System.schedule(jobName, cronExp, new WarehouseSyncSchedule());
            } catch (AsyncException e) {
                System.debug('Error scheduling job: ' + e.getMessage());
                 requirements
            }
        }
    
        private static void abortExistingJob() {
            List<CronTrigger> existingJobs = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = :jobName LIMIT 1];
            if (!existingJobs.isEmpty()) {
                System.abortJob(existingJobs[0].Id);
            }
        }
    }

My test Class :
    @IsTest
    public class WarehouseSyncScheduleTest {
        
        @IsTest
        static void testScheduledJob(){
            String cronExp = '0 0 1 * * ?';
            Test.startTest();
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WarehouseCalloutServiceMock());
            WarehouseCalloutService queueable = new WarehouseCalloutService();
            queueable.execute(null);
            String jobID = System.schedule('WarehouseSyncScheduleJob', cronExp, new WarehouseSyncSchedule());
            Test.stopTest();
            CronTrigger a = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE NextFireTime > today AND Id =: jobID];
            
            System.assertEquals(jobID, a.Id,'Schedule');
           
        }
    }

Just wanted to know, Am I doing anything wrong here?
The error message:

System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached.                                                      Class.WarehouseCalloutService.performCallout: line 37, column 1
Class.WarehouseCalloutService.execute: line 18, column 1


Have you tried doing a search here or reading the docs? There are many Q&As explaining this error.

Refer to this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T439ZSAR
